# C# How to pass ARRAY from another Method

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner with C# and I need little help. I'm not sure how can I take 'studentArray' from CreateStudent() and use it at ViewAllStudents(). Any help is appreciated!

```
        static void CreateStudent()
        {
            // User Inputs 
            Console.WriteLine("Student Name: ");
            var name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Student Surname: ");
            var surname = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Student ID: ");
            var id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            var student = new Students(name, surname, id); // Student Constructor

            // Create Array and Resize it 
            Students[] studentArray = new Students[] { student };
            Array.Resize(ref studentArray, studentArray.Length + 1);
            studentArray[studentArray.GetUpperBound(0)] = student;

            Console.WriteLine($"Student {student.Name} {student.Surname} with ID {student.StudentId} is successfully created!");
        }
        static void ViewAllStudents()
        {
            foreach(var student in studentArray)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"\t {student}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change return type of CreateStudent from void to Students[] and return "studentArray" . Change the parameter type of ViewAllStudents() to "ViewAllStudents(Students[] studentArray )" .I hope the following will work.

```
static Students[] CreateStudent()
{
    // User Inputs 
    Console.WriteLine("Student Name: ");
    var name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Student Surname: ");
    var surname = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Student ID: ");
    var id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    var student = new Students(name, surname, id); // Student Constructor

    // Create Array and Resize it 
    Students[] studentArray = new Students[] { student };
    Array.Resize(ref studentArray, studentArray.Length + 1);
    studentArray[studentArray.GetUpperBound(0)] = student;

    Console.WriteLine($"Student {student.Name} {student.Surname} with ID {student.StudentId} is successfully created!");
     return studentArray;
}

static void ViewAllStudents(Student[] studentArray)
{
    foreach(var student in studentArray)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\t {student}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Demir...I'd take it one step further and show in `main()` (presumably) how you'd capture the return value of `CreateStudent()` and then pass that along to `ViewAllStudents()`.